# Create movie file using binary files

Tags: qt, binaryfiles, movie

I want to create a movie file from binary files. I am able to read binary files using following code

```
QFile myfile;
int fnum,
myfile.setFileName(“c:/file%d.bin”,fnum);
if(!myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;
QDataStream data(&myfile);
data.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
QVector<qint16> result;
while(!data.atEnd()) { qint16 x; data >> x; result.append(x);
}
```

here fnum is the number of frames and represents a binary file... can anyone share an idea for how to create a movie file from these data.. at the moment I am able read a frame and plot an intensity plot using qwtspectrogram. but I also want to save the complete movie.

Comment: What format are these "binary files" in?

Comment: Read frame, then save it to the movie file, repeat until all frames in all input files are proceeded? You probably want existing library or two, which can encode the movie from individual frames, and covert your binary file frames into a format understood by the movie file encoder.

Comment: they are in .bin format